# Nancy concurrent requests running synchronously

Tags: c#, concurrency, nancy

I was expecting the below code to be able handle multiple requests all with a 5 second delay, however if 2 requests come in at the same time, the second request takes 10 seconds (it waits for the first one to finish). What am I missing here?

```
public class Test : NancyModule
{
    public Test()
    {
        Get["/", runAsync: true] = async (x, ct) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before");
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("After");
            return "Hello World";
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I know nothing about nancy.  But it does seem like what you posted should work. Question: When do you see the 2nd `Before` string written to the console?  Is it as soon as you send your 2nd request, or is there a 5 second delay before you see it?  It would be useful if you edited your post with what is written to the console along with timestamps for each write.

Comment: @sstan It shows after the 5 second delay of the first request :(

Comment: That's what I thought.  That means that your method is actually coded correctly, and the reason why your requests are serialized is probably more upstream.  What tool are you using to send both requests at the same time?

Comment: @sstan At the moment I am just using multiple browser windows, I can have 3 windows open, hit refresh on all of them, and the last one will take 15 seconds to show "Hello World"

Comment: Are all your windows using the same browser type?  Like, are they all *Internet Explorer*, or all *Chrome*, etc?  If so, try using a different browser type per window.  1 window is *Internet Explorer*, your other window is *Chrome*, etc.  Sometimes I have noticed that the browser itself will prevent proper concurrent request testing.

Comment: @sstan Wow, That was it! Using IE I get expected behavior. Chrome was the culprit! Thankyou so much!

Comment: @sstan How do I add your comment as the answer?

Comment: I added an answer.  I'm glad it's resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct.

The problem is that if you test generating concurrent requests using a single web browser type, depending on which browser you use, the browser itself may prevent sending concurrent requests.

To be safe, I recommend you mix in multiple browser types to generate concurrent requests.